# input field unnecessary property is taking in IOS device

Tags: html, css, dojo, hybrid-mobile-app

we are developing hybrid mobile application using dojo 1.10.3 .

all devices text field is coming UI is good except iPhone environment text field inside top portion unwanted property(black color border and shadow) coming that is not looking good.

In that input field we are not able to  find it what is that exactly property

we are taking some input fields and adding css properties like below

```css
.textbox{
    margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
 font-size: 12px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-indent: 10px;
 color: rgba(23, 82, 117, 1.0);
 display: block;
 width: 85%;
 height: 34px;
 border: 1px solid rgba(204, 204, 204, 1.0);
 border-radius: 0px;
 background-color: white !important;
 outline: none !important;
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 0px transparent;
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 0px transparent;
 box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 0px transparent;
  }
```

```html
<input data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TextBox"  class="textbox">

<input data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TextBox"  class="textbox">

<input data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TextBox"  class="textbox">
```

and textfeild default css code in iphone.css like below

```css
.mblTextBox {
  height: 22px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: inset;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  font-size: 13px;
  border-color: #9cacc0;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

i am attaching screen shots Please find my problem easily understand

we want like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zk44f.png)

actual problem below like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciiFt.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding: `-webkit-appearance: none;` to all input elements in CSS.

The input below should appear the same on all browsers (including mobile Safari)

```css
input[type=text] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 0px;
  outline: none;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

**Edit:**
It seems that you're problem could also be solved via this way: https://davidwalsh.name/input-shadows-ipad

**Edit 2:**
I've tried the example below multiple times and it should definitely work. If not, you're using some CSS rules that might override one (or more) of the rules from the example.

*Result on iPhone Simulator:*
[image: iPhone Simulator result]

```css
ul.examples {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: Arial;
}
.textbox {
  margin: 5px 0px 10px 0px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid rgba(204, 204, 204, 1.0);
  border-radius: 0px;
  outline: none !important;
}
.example:last-child .textbox {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="examples">
  <li class="example">Your example:
    <br/>
    <input data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TextBox" class="textbox">
  </li>
  <li class="example">My example:
    <br/>
    <input data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TextBox" class="textbox">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: we are using type mail,password,text,number and file we are facing problem in all types of input fields

Comment: You could try to clear your cache since the example above is working fine for me on multiple devices.

Comment: Maybe the text `color` is the same as the `background-color` of the input?

Comment: no it is light green color: rgba(23, 82, 117, 1.0);

Comment: But my example is working? If so, there is a bug in your CSS.